# How to round corners in Custom Shapes in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

> I want to add round corner (corner radius) in my custom shape. I'm having trouble using *path.addCurve* or *path.addArc*

[My Custom Shape Image in SwiftUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UtZc.png)

```
import SwiftUI

struct ProDetails: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ThemeShape()
                .frame(height: 450)
                .foregroundColor(.mint)
            Spacer()
        } .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)

    }
}

struct ThemeShape: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        Path { path in
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.midY))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX + 80, y: rect.midY))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX + 80, y: rect.maxY))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))
        }
    }
}

struct ProDetails_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ProDetails()
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/drawing-paths-and-shapes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```swift
struct ThemeShape: Shape {
  func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
    Path { path in
      path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.midY))
      path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX + 80, y: rect.midY))
      path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.maxY * 0.75),
                    control1: CGPoint(x: rect.minX + 80 + 30, y: rect.midY),
                    control2: CGPoint(x: rect.minX + 80 + 30, y: rect.midY))
      path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - 80, y: rect.maxY),
                    control1: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - 80 - 30, y: rect.maxY),
                    control2: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - 80 - 30, y: rect.maxY))
      path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
      path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))
      path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))
    }
  }
}
```

[image]